# Unix text based browser with javascript support

Tags: angularjs, unix, browser, terminal

I need to perform smoke-test of my AngularJS application on Unix, from terminal.
I tried accessing application from

- links2
- links
- w3m
- elinks
- lynx

All above-mentioned browsers show empty screen. In most of them I am able to view source using \ (backslash), so I could do basic verification if application server works properly at least.

Is there any unix text browser with javascript support? I am not looking for complete support (so application would be usable).
It would be great to have ability just to view some elements of the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install *libmozjs* (on debian/ubuntu `aptitude install libmozjs185-dev`), then (don't forget to do a *sudo ldconfig* first) compile from the source elinks.

```
wget http://elinks.or.cz/download/elinks-current-0.13.tar.bz2
tar xjvf elinks-current-0.13.tar.bz2
cd elinks-0.13*
./configure
make -j8
sudo make install
```

Check after ./configure if *ECMAScript* is flagged *SpiderMonkey document scripting*.

p.s. Ubuntu 14.04 here.

Comment: You will need to install libmozjs185-dev pkg-config as explained there :
[link](https://www.cnx-software.com/2014/02/09/building-elinks-text-based-web-browser-with-some-sort-of-javascript-support/)

Answer (score 2):

I guess the best way to do it would be with a headless browser such as PhantomJS http://phantomjs.org/. It has a programmable interface, so you can run a simple JS script to open your webpage, and do a simple check.

Or, you can write a more complete test using Protractor https://github.com/angular/protractor. It will give you a nice API to write tests targeting Selenium Webdriver http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/, that can target many browsers, including PhantomJS.

If you do a lot of AngularJS development you should take a look a Protractor anyway.

Comment: google chrome headless browser is launched already which has way better JS support then phantomjs https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome